# how to use mysql to count the total number of all race?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a set of data inside the database.applicant, i want to count the total number of all the race and display it as

Chinese 22
Malay   50
etc

but i do not know how to write the SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not given details of the table like column name, I write the following SQL Query according to my assumption. Hope it will help.

`SELECT applicant_race, COUNT(applicant_race) AS total_race_num FROM database.applicant GROUP BY applicant_race`

Comment: thanks, i got the answer

SELECT RACE, COUNT(RACE) AS total_race_num FROM applicant GROUP BY RACE